# Simplest Proof for an Elementary Number Theory Condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have to proove in the most 'primitive' way the following:

if $ab=ac$ then either $a=0$ or $b=c$.

I could think only about the following solution:
considering the given $ab=ac$, let's subtract from both sides of the equation $ac$. Thus we get $ab-ac=0$. It means that:

1. either both $ab$ and $ac$ equal $0$, so the difference equals $0$,
2. or $ab$ and $ac$ represent a real number, so it is possible to multiply $ab$ and $ac$ both by $1/a$. This way we get that $b-c=0$, so $b=c$ as asked,
3. or $b\neq c$, so $a$ must be zero.

I'm not very sure about step 3.

Comment: Be careful.  It is only possible to multiply $ab$ and $ac$ by $1/a$ if we know that $a \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, IMO,  would be the following:

$-ac$ from both sides gives you $ab-ac=0$
Left distibutitivity gives you $a(b-c)=0$.
The fact that you're in an integral domain thus gives you either $a=0$ or $b-c=0$, in the latter case, add $c$ to either side to get $b=c

Comment: first of all it's the real numbers domain. secondly, I'm not sure if I can use the distributivity here. tried to avoid this use.

Comment: The real numbers are an example of an integral domain, an integral domain is any number system in which $ab=0$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$

Answer (score 2):

a is either equal to 0 or not.if a is 0 then your are done.
if a is not 0 then you can devide by a and get b=c